# Broken link on tag info page for unregistered users

Tags: bug, status-completed, suggested-edits, tag-wiki, unregistered-users

The "improve description" link on tag info pages is shown to all users:

[image: Screenshot of the info box]

But unregistered users can't suggest edits to tag descriptions, so it just leads to a 404 page

Answer (score 4, accepted):

fixed, to be deployed later ... the invitation to edit was also a problem for blank tags.