# "Saves" for unregistered user gives 404 page

Tags: bug, 404-not-found, unregistered-users, saves

The link to [saves](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/saves/current/all) gives a 404 page when used from an unregistered user profile:

> [image]

If it's not suitable for unregistered users, could we just remove that section for them? I didn't find any restrictions related to unregistered users from the announcement: [Bookmarks have evolved into Saves](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/382019/339911)

The Saves link from the left navigation menu produces the same behavior:

> [image]

At the same time, an attempt to add a post into saves leads to a popup with a request to log in (weird wording, since actually I logged in, but not registered):

> [image]

Much better wording is used for post "following" ability:

> [image]

<sup>* image was autotranslated to English</sup>

Comment: The correct response code _is_ 404, but perhaps it could do with a more informative message: perhaps “please register your account to use this feature”.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 why do you think that 404 is correct response here?

Comment: I assume saves aren't implemented for unregistered users. It seems like a lot of resources used for no real benefit: unregistered accounts are lost as soon as the cookies go away, so SE would just be storing a load of data that nobody could ever access again. 404 is the correct HTTP response for "there's nothing here, and never has been".

Comment: The bug is having a link to Saves. e.g. when logged out, no link in sidebar which is the expected behavior, same should be for unregistered users.

Comment: [Related bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98078/broken-link-on-tag-info-page-for-unregistered-users), of link leading to 404 showing for unregistered users. Fixed in less than 2 hours. Good old times, that won't be back. :/

Comment: @wizzwizz4 I would say that the UI should not offer a clickable option that will always fail. For unregistered accounts it should be removed or else dimmed and made unclickable.